Difference between "get something off your chest" and "make a clean breast of it"
Are there any differences in the meaning of or when we use the idioms 'get something off your chest' and 'make a clean breast of it'? The definitions in the Cambridge Dictionary are:

get something off your chest: to tell someone about something that has been worrying you or making you feel guilty for a long time
make a clean breast of it: to tell the truth about something


They're very different. What don't you understand about the dictionary definitions?

@Barmar According to situations that I've seen they've been used, I thought they are sort of similar. So then I looked up them in the dictionary. Can you please tell me exactly what these very differences are?

get something off your chest can be about sharing an experience, or telling a secret, or giving a personal opinion

There's some overlap. When you admit to something that has been worrying you, you're usually telling the truth. But the emphasis is completely different.

In the first, you are sharing something so that you feel better about what's bothering you. In the second, you are confessing something that you probably should not have done.

I have read and heard of UK men 'getting the dirty water off their chest' which means something sordid.

It's worth noting that "clean breast" is a 19th-Century expression, whereas "off your chest" is a 20th-Century expression. An average listener/reader is somewhat unlikely to be familiar with "clean breast" tho it's not totally archaic. Most modern users are making dumb jokes about breasts rather than using it in earnest.

Personally, I have never heard "make a clean breast of it", and would have to look up what it means. It could be a US/UK thing (I'm USian), or it could be as others suggest a somewhat antiquated phrase.

OP has enquired about the difference between two idioms :

Are there any differences in the meaning of or when we use the idioms 'get something off your chest' and 'make a clean breast of it'?

Even though both of these activities can help you feel less anxious, the circumstances are different..
Let's consider them separately:
I. get something off your chest:.
It is sharing your problem with someone.
Some issue is weighing you down (financial problems, emotional problems).  Talking to someone helps reduce the burden. Finding a solution to the issue could be aided by speaking with someone who is not involved in the circumstance.
You can give a call to phone counselling service, if you don't think you can talk to someone you know about the issue.
II. make a clean breast of it.
You have harmed someone in some way. Confessing your sin would be of great help.
If you feel guilty about something then it will be necessary for you to confess it in some way, in order to feel free.
If, for example, you sinned against someone specific, then the best way forward is to speak to the person you sinned against, expressing your regret. Aside from trying to not make the same mistake again, that is the best you can do.
The primary distinction between the two is that, in the first instance, you are attempting to solve your own issue.
In the second case, you admit to being guilty of  wrongdoing.

get something off your chest is used far more often than make a clean breast of it.  I would wager than many speakers of AmE are unfamiliar with the latter but almost all of them are familiar with the former.
The two do overlap. To "get something off your chest" means to speak to someone about something that has been bothering you, and that thing could be something you feel guilty about, which is how "make a clean breast of it"  is used. But in "to get something off your chest",  the something could be what someone else has done, and you want to let them know that what they have done has been bothering you. Perhaps you feel offended, or disappointed with them, or angry.

Just for the sake of statistical completeness, make a clean breast of it is perfectly common in British English, if perhaps a bit old-fashioned. It’s possible many AmE speakers would be unfamiliar with it, but I’m fairly sure virtually all BrE speakers would know it.

I would say that perhaps  10% of AmE speakers would know what it means, maybe even less.  But I don't want to park myself on chair at the mall by the fountain and take a poll.  I might get carted off by mall security as a perv for asking people about "making clean breasts".  Whisper-down-the-lane risk.
